# Pycharm file-reading program works in debug mode but fails in release mode?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've written a script that reads values from a text file into dictionary object my_dict. I have two files, one that is 35mb and one that is 4.1Gb. On my system I have 8gb of memory and a hearty 32gb swap file.

The files sort of look like this:

dict_key_a 1,2,3,4,5,6 ...

dict_key_b 7,8,9,1,2,3 ...

...

Here is the function I am using to convert them to dictionaries:

```
import os
import time

def unpack_dictionary(directory, verbose=False):
    start_time = time.time()
    if verbose:
        print("[Reading data from file {}]".format(directory))
    my_dict  = dict()
    file = open(directory)
    count = 0
    for line in file:
        print(count)
        count = count + 1  #I used this to figure out where it is stopping
        id, data = line.split()
        my_dict[id] = list(map(float, data.split(',')))

    file.close()

    file_size = os.path.getsize(directory)

    if verbose:
        print("[Finished reading {} GB in {} seconds]".format(file_size / 1000000000, round((time.time() - start_time), 3)))
    return my_dict
```

I'm working in Pycharm, and this program always reads the first 35mb file quickly. However, when reading the larger 4gb file, the program freezes on entry 4188 always.

I tried running with the debugger and the program works fine. However, it takes 20gb of my swap file, which seems unnecessary. I was expecting at most 8gb (4gb to read the file, and 4gb to hold the dictionary). What could all this extra memory be used for? I am not running any other programs...

I can see in HTOP that 86% of my memory is allocated to the virtual environment.

When I run the process out of my virtual environment, it only gets to 2352....

Python 3.6 64-Bit on Ubuntu 18

Comment: Are you running the 64 bit version of Python?

Comment: @DanielF Yes, the output of import struct;print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8) is 64